# simple chat using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm not so good at English but I will give it a try, feel free to edit and improve my post!

I'm trying to create a little chat, now I do not want to reload when there's no new data. It will receive the data from update.php, this works correctly.

I'm trying to do a little check (sample to show what I want to accomplish):

This is standard:

```
var ok = update.php
load ok(4000s);
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is:

```
var ok = update.php
function timer{
var new = update.php
if(new != ok){
  ok = new;
},4000};
```

Of course this is fake code, it would never run, but it's the easiest way to explain what I mean.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("#chatbox").html('').load("update.php");
                   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    var xx = $("#chatbox").html('').load("update.php");
                    $('#holder').load('update.php');
                    if( xx != "#holder"){
                        $("#chatbox").html('').load('update.php');

                        // $("#chatbox").html('').load('update.php')
                        $("#chatbox").scrollTop($("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight);  
                    }else{
                     alert)('nooope');
                    }
               }, 4000);
               $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            });
```

I tried everything, still getting nope.
(chatbox is a div, where de data gets loaded into.)
(holder is the same concept, only this one is hided trough css, so that the user won't notice.)

Comment: You seem to by trying to make an AJAX request, but `new = update.php` is not the right way to do that. So, first of all, search a bit for AJAX to find out how to request and load data in the background, and also use the developer tools (F12), and especially the JavaScript console in it, to find any syntax errors in your script. Without it, you're practically blindfolded.

Comment: search for socket.io and see chat demos .

Comment: @GolezTrol No that was just explanation code of what I wanted to accomplish, the real code is the Jquery one :p

Comment: @danialdezfooli Thanks, I'll give it a try. But you can't review this code? (The Jquery part) Because I really wanted to create the chat without any other plugins then AJAX and Jquery

Comment: this way is not currect ! in socket.io whene message sent in js we call a function , but in your code every 4 seconds browser should send data

Comment: @danialdezfooli If I'm right it does not send data, it receives data? (every 4 seconds)

Comment: if you want to continue this way , You have to use $.ajax in setInterval